# heapify function recursing endlessly

Tags: recursion, heap, priority-queue, binary-heap

The following is a recursive heapify function for an array based priority queue/binary heap.

Can anybody tell me why I'm going into an infinite recursion?

```
private static void heapify(int i){

    if(i < b_heap.size()/2){

        int left = i * 2;
        int right = left++;

        if(b_heap.get(i).getP() > b_heap.get(left).getP()){
            swap(i,left);
        }
        if(b_heap.get(i).getP() > b_heap.get(right).getP()){
            swap(i,right);
        }

        heapify(i++);
        heapify(i+2);
    }
    else{
        return;
    }
}
```

---

ok so I fixed the infinite loop, but the function still doesn't heapify correctly.

here is the new code,

```
private static void heapify(int i){
    DecimalFormat df = new DecimalFormat("0.00");
    if(i < b_heap.size()/2){
        int left = i * 2;
        int right = i * 2 +1;

        if(b_heap.get(i).getP() > b_heap.get(left).getP()){
            swap(i,left);
        }
        if(b_heap.get(i).getP() > b_heap.get(right).getP()){
            swap(i,right);
        }
        i++;
        heapify(i);
    }
    else{
        return;
    }
}
```

Comment: I'm not really sure what the _i_ parameter does but if it's given a value, the _left_ and _right_ local variables are always the same value since left++ is evaluated __after__ being assigned to _right_. Similar thing is happening with heapify(i++) where the increment is evaluated after the call. Following these series of events, infinite recursion happens.

Comment: So the most useful thing you can do at this point is add a ton of print statements or walk through it in some kind of IDE. I tend towards the print statements initially so I can spot if anything extremely obvious is happening, then start walking my code if nothing looks to suspect. 

I'd:
 print i and b_heap.size() before the if
 print i and b_heap.size() inside the if
 print i and left in the second if
 print i and right in the third if
 print i before the return

Comment: You call heapify with `i++`: this gives heapify `i` and then increments it.

Comment: And also you do `left++`. I think you need to read up on what the `++` operator does. It is NOT the same thing as `+1`.

Comment: Thanks everybody. The error was the i++, I got it to recurse correctly.  However the heap it produces is still wrong. did I implement the switches correctly for a min heap?

Comment: @jokeSlayer94 Well, you don't individually check whether the child indices are valid, and for some reason you've chosen to recursively `heapify` the next two elements, rather than one child. So no, not even close.